# Умеет ли Composer определять среду, в которой он запущен?

Tags: composer

Как известно из [официального руководства](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) данного инструмента, при выполнении команд update или install мы можем указать опцию --no-dev, которая укажет, что не нужно обрабатывать пакеты, указанные в разделе require-dev в файле composer.json (или ином, указанном при запуске).

Данная опция может использоваться при разворачивании приложения на production-сервере(ах). Это достаточно удобно, когда используется некий скрипт автоматического разворачивания. Однако, если делать это вручную, зачастую можно забыть указать эту опцию и получить ненужные пакеты.

Так вот, сам вопрос: можно ли каким-либо стандартным образом один раз и навсегда указать Composer'у, что некая одна среда является средой разработки, а некая другая - средой использования приложения, дабы не требовалось каждый раз указывать те или иные опции при его запуске?